# .load() Method on a non-DIV element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I've built a small site to test using the `.load()` method to load the contents of an element. While .load works if I place the target element inside `<div>` tags, I can't get it to work on just the target element, a page title in `<h1>` tags. Is there a way to load content using `.load()` without placing `<div>` tags around every affected element in my HTML?

**My HTML for page 1:**

```
<body>
<h1 id="pagetitle">Page 1</h1>
<p>Some paragraph text</p>
<a id="page2">page 2</a>
</body>
```

For page 2, the HTML is the same, except the title is `<h1>Page 2<h1>`.

**My jQuery:**

```
$('a#page2').click(function () {
$("#pagetitle").load("page2.html #pagetitle > *");
});
```

From everything I've read, clicking #page2 should load the contents of the #pagetitle  tags from page2.html, but the content isn't added - instead, the content ("page 1") just dissapears.

However, if I add `<div>` tags around the `<h1>` elements and load the divs instead:

```
$("div#pagetitle").load("page2.html div#pagetitle > *");
```

The content is replaced. However, in the interest of keeping my HTML uncluttered, I'd like to avoid this if there's a better way.

Comment: This fails because `h1` element has no descendant elements. Remove the `> *`.

Comment: @undefined, I've noticed that seems to add a second <h1> element inside the first, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: @Barmar, my mistake, my <h1> does have an ID but I forgot it in the excerpt above; edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`> *` selects direct children of the `#pagetitle` element, in your markup `h1` element doesn't have any descendant element, so the query fails and it returns nothing, remove the `> *` selector and it should work. However, it will add the loaded `h1` element to the the current `h1` element, jQuery `.load()` methods uses `$.get()` utility function, you can use this function to replace the element or change the `innerHTML` property of the current `h1` element. This gives you more control over the loaded html.

```
$('#page2').click(function(event) {
   // event.preventDefault();
   $.get('page2.html', function(data) {
       $("#pagetitle").html(function() {
            return $(data).find('#pagetitle').html();
       });
   }, 'html');
});
```